# Получение информации по внешним ключам

Tags: php, symfony3, doctrine2

Имеются две сущности: User, Role. Каждый инстанс сущности User содержит в себе внешний ключ roleID ссылающийся на поле id сущности Role.

Что сделано:

1. Собственно, помощью `Doctrine` сгенерировал вышеуказанные сущности
2. Добавил аннотации к полям
3. Сгенерировал CRUD контроллер для каждой из сущностей

Контроллер содержит метод indexAction(...), который выдает весь список пользователей. На данный момент выводится информации о roleID, но хотелось бы там видеть roleName. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализуется.

indexAction(...):

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $users = $em->getRepository('ManagementBundle:User')->findAll();

        return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', array(
            'users' => $users,
        ));
    }
```

---

*Framework: Symfony (v.3.3.10), ORM - Doctrine*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так понял должна присоединиться роль к пользователю. Тогда это реализуется примерно так:

```
$entity = $em
    ->getRepository('ManagementBundle:User')
    ->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->join('u.Role', 'r')
    ->where('r.id = 1')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Как альтернатива.
Если вы уже имеете пользователя то можно вызвать и следующим способом.

```
$User->getRole();
```

Если отношении один ко многим то вы получите то доктрина вам вернёт Persistent collection которую нужно перебрать в цикле.

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас (после того, как правильно написал аннотации :)) так и делаю.

Comment: Только не злоупотребляйте, так как в таком случае работает "ленивая загрузка" и при больших запросах она не эффективна. В первом варианте она кстати тоже отрабатывает.